# How can I show the Emacs menu in GUI emacs frames but not in tty frames when using emacs daemon mode

Tags: emacs

I start an emacs daemon which I connect to both from long-lived GUI emacs frames and short-lived tty emacs frames. I currently use the following in my .emacs.d/init.el:

```
(if (not window-system) (menu-bar-mode 0))
```

Unfortunately this is a global setting so it applies to all frames. I'd prefer to have the menu only on my GUI frames; the menu takes up too much space on tty frames.

Is there a way of making this setting frame-specific?

Thanks.

Comment: While I agree that this question is appropriate to SuperUser, I think you might have better luck on StackOverflow. Unfortunately, the SO crowd may punt it back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is frame-specific: each frame has a `menu-bar-lines` parameter. In fact `menu-bar-mode` loops through all frames to set this parameter. To set the parameter for a the current frame:

```
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'menu-bar-lines 1) ; or 0 for off
```

The next step is to set the parameter each time a frame is created:

```
(defun set-frame-menu-bar-lines (frame)
  (let ((want-menu (memq (framep frame) '(x w32 ns))))
    (set-frame-parameter frame 'menu-bar-lines (if want-menu 1 0))))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'set-frame-menu-bar-lines)
```